# Complete animation, THEN scroll to div

Tags: jquery, scroll

Ok, this one has me. I'm trying to make my page run a bunch of sequential animation on elements, and when its done, THEN scroll to a div named START. I've got the animation bit down but the whole auto scrolling thing has me beat. No matter what code I stole and tried, it just didn't work.

ANy anyone point me in the right direction? This is the code I was trying at the bottom:

```
$(function () {
    $("a.engine").click(function () {
        $("div.intro_image").removeClass("intro_effects");
        $("body").animate(500).css({
            "overflow": "auto"
        });
        $("div.menu_container").delay(600).animate(500).removeClass("hide");
        $('a.engine').contents().unwrap();

    });

    function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
        var aTag = $("a[name='" + aid + "']");
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    }

    $("a.engine").click(function () {
        scrollToAnchor('start');
    });

});
```

Comment: Please tell us what didn't work. Error messages? No scroll? Just saying it doesn't work doesn't describe the problem well.

Comment: Sorry abou that.

It doesn't scroll. All the animations complete, and then it just sits there all proud. No scrolling down though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using setTimeout

```
  $(function () {
  $("a.engine").click(function () {
    $("div.intro_image").removeClass("intro_effects");
    $("body").animate(500).css({
        "overflow": "auto"
    });
    $("div.menu_container").delay(600).animate(500).removeClass("hide");
    $('a.engine').contents().unwrap();
    setTimeout(function(){
     scrollToAnchor('start');
     },1100);
});

function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
    var aTag = $("a[name='" + aid + "']");
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```

});

and check value of aTag.offset().top in debugger.